# Menus and mobile sites

Tags: theming

We're using a theme based off Adaptive Theme, but even dropping columns below the main content still has undesired rendering outcome. When `region-sidebar-first` drops below `content-inner` there is a problem -- since the link colors contained within sidebar first and the body background color are both white.

[image]

What I'd like to have happen is that for mobile devices or when the browser size is under a certain width, I'd like to remove `region-sidebar-first` and `region-sidebar-second` and move the menu into another field that into another collapisable region to function as a 'mobile menu'.

Question: Could context handle this? Is there a mobile to handle such logic?

Current our setting appear as follows
[image]

Comment: You'll struggle to make such a workflow _responsive_ in the true definition of the word. Context can make decisions by browser sniffing, but the idea of responsive theming is that you design for mobile **first**, and that the server-side doesn't get involved. As such, if you need something on >=narrow layouts that you specifically don't want in the mobile theme, the answer is to hide it with CSS.

Comment: Yes, I'd much rather approach rules based on width than on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a CSS question I think. I solved this problem already for various sites using another menu block, with its own css markup, or using a [jump menu](http://drupal.org/project/jump_menu/).

Using media queries you will have to set the threshold on where to break:

```
@media all and (max-width: 370px) {
    .default-menu-region {
        display:none;
    }
    .mobile-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 371px) {
    .mobile-menu {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Adaptive theme provides files for those media queries already, you can just drop your custom content in there instead of writing new media queries like in this example.

Comment: Well this would certainly settle the short range problem of white link and background color. Thank you also for a very clear example of how to build the CSS media rules.